# MxN grid (matrix) problem for getting possible paths

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7

I have an MxN matrix (filled with only 0's and 1's, I have to "count" all the possible unique paths.
Consider the below example:

```
grid =[[1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

```
The rules of the solution are:
1) A path can be of length 1
2) A path should contains only 1's
3) Diagonal 1's are not part of a path, they stand alone as 1 path. They can be part of a path if they have adjacent 1's.  for Eg:

    grid_example =[[1, 0],
                   [0, 1]] - This grid has 2 paths, first row 1 is one path and second-row 1 is the other path


With the above rules, the initial grid has 3 path
    a) The two 1's in row 1
    b) The single 1 in row 2
    c) The series of seven 1's in row 4 and 5
```

I am trying to think of an algorithm on how to solve this, but I am stumped. Does anybody know an algorithm that can solve this? I need to write a python code for the same. I don't need the code. Just the algorithm.

Other examples include:

```
grid =[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
This has 5 paths. Each 1 in the diagonal form a path, since diagonal 1's cannot be part of path
```

This is the answer that worked:

```
def countIslands(rows, column, grid):
    def remove(i, j):
        if 0 <= i < rows and 0 <= j < column and grid[i][j] == 1:
            grid[i][j] = 0
            for x,y in zip([i+1, i-1, i, i], [j, j, j+1, j-1]):
                remove(x,y) 
            return 1
        return 0
    return sum(remove(i, j) for i in range(rows) for j in range(column))

grid = [[1,1,0,1],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1],[1,1,1,1]]
rows = 5
column = 4
final = countIslands(rows, column, grid)
print(final)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider your grid as an [undirected graph](https://mathinsight.org/definition/undirected_graph):

- **vertices** are cells with 1s;
- two vertices have an **edge** between them iff these vertices are vertically or horizontally adjacent

'Path' in your problem means a [connected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) in graph terms. So you have to count these components. This could be done by [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) algorithm.

Here is an equivalent [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-islands/) with provided solutions in a discuss section.

Comment: That helped @gimme_danger. I have updated my answer in the original question

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want to get number of connected components (usting 4-connectivity)

[Arbitrary found example](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-count-number-of-connected-components-in-an-undirected-graph/)

Also look at [Connected-component_labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling)  (overkill for your current problem because you don't need mark components)